# Will {position: absolute;} always position my element with respect to its first parent?

Tags: html, css, position

There are many div elements on my page

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="second">
        <div class="third">
            <div class="important_div"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to position ".important_div" with respect to `.first`. and in order to do this, I use the `position: absolute;` property:

```
.important_div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Now here are my questions:

1)When I use absolute positioning, it positions my `.important_div` in respect to `.third` (father of `.important_div`). I want to position it in respect to `.first` div (great-grandfather of `.important_div`). What should I do?

2)Does *{position: absolute}* position my element always in respect to its parent?

3)Is there another way to position `.important_div` at the bottom of `.first` div, maybe using absolute or something similar?

Comment: Check the demo on JS fiddle from my answer.

Answer (score 7):

It's relative to the first nearest *positioned* ancestor. So, if `.third` has positioning, it gets positioned relative to that element. Likewise, if `.second` has positioning (but not `.third`), it is positioned relative to that. If no elements have positioning, it's relative to the document container.

Here's a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mnKpu/1/

Comment: let's  say my all divs has positioned. how should i position my "important_div" respect to "first"?

Comment: I know this is stating the obvious, but if you can modify the markup, the easiest way is to move `important_div` from `third` and as an immediate child of `first`. If modifying the markup isn't possible (and let's say CSS is set from a CMS), you *could* override the positioning values of `second` and `third` so that the `important_div` has the correct parent.

Comment: override means delete in here?

Comment: Override is actually setting the value of position back to their initial value. `position: initial` is one way, although it's not supported by IE yet. Instead, you can do `position: static`, which is the initial value. Here's a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/mnKpu/

Answer (score 1):

Apply:

```
position: relative;
```

to your `.first` div. And do not apply `position: relative;` to your `.third` div if you want to position your `.important` div relative to your `.first` div.

**[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uaFgM/2/)** here: